# SQL multiples unpivot

Tags: sql, select, union, transpose, unpivot

I'm having some difficult with multiples unpivot and also tried APPLY. 
So Lets say I have:

```
[name]   [Type1name]  [Type2name]  [Region1] [region2]  [Type1valu] [type2value] 
abc       car          bike            US        JP       500         300
def       car          boat            US        UK       150         200
ghi       boat         *null*          BR        *null*    50          *null*

now I want to aggregate [Type1name] + [Type2name] and [Region1] + [Region2] on same columns and values in each respective line:

[name]  [Typename]  [Region] [Value]
abc     car            US     500
abc     bike           JP     300
def     car            US     150  
def     boat           UK     200
ghi     boat           BR     50
```

Comment: SQL what? What have you tried?

Comment: Add the what ever you have tried so far in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.name, A.Type1name AS Typename, A.Region1 AS Region, A.Type1value AS 'Value'
FROM tableA A 
WHERE A.Type1name IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT A.name, A.Type2name AS Typename, A.Region2 AS Region, A.Type2value AS 'Value'
FROM tableA A
WHERE A.Type2name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: simple and perfect, tnks